# Spring 3.2-HIbernate3-Tiles - Display Tag not working

Tags: spring, hibernate, displaytag, tiles2

I searched a lot on web, And I found how to use display tag with spring. But my problem is different am developing a travel agency app using spring as above mentioned version. And I am trying to use the below mentioned display tag version. Without these jars my app is running fine.

I am using itext-1.3.jar, displaytag-1.2.jar, displaytag-export-poi-1.2.jar, jcl104-over-slf4j-1.4.2.jar and poi-3.2-FINAL.jar

But whenever I include these jars in my app I am getting the following error. Please help me.

```
HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet spring-dispatcher threw exception

type Exception report

message javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet spring-dispatcher threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet spring-dispatcher threw exception
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet spring-dispatcher threw exception
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:750)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:720)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:72)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 

    org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
        org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.debug(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:99)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:118)
        javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:750)
        org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:720)
        org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:72)
        org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

    note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 logs.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what other jars you have? commons-logging? also check maven dependency tree for other slf4j jars.

Comment: Thank for your contribution. first of all am not using maven.

Comment: I am using spring mvc 3 jars , hibernate and tiles jars. With this my app is working fine.At some point I need to get pagination. Whenever I included these jars in eclipse am getting this error. Without these display jars my app is running fine.

Comment: I Need to know what is the problem with these jars. Whether the version is not suitable or what else the problem is.........

Comment: Yes, the version should be the problem. It is loading only one of the for slf4j, but calls made to different version.

Comment: let you know I am usign the following jars.